# Is it possible to publish HTML code in Facebook streams?

Tags: facebook, api, stream, publish

i need to publish some text in the wall of my users (i'm writing an application visible inside FB using IFRAME). The question is: is it possible to publish HTML code (with CSS inline) to pages and users wall ?

Is is possible to show flash content directly in the wall ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML code and CSS are not possible. When posting using stream.publish you can post just plain text.

If you need to post some other media with your story you can use the stream attachment.

One optional field is the `media` field which provides visual content for the post. The available types are image, flash, or music.

General example for attaching flash content is:

> {"media": [{
>       "type": "flash", 
>       "swfsrc": "http://www.x.com/flash.swf",
>
> ```
> "imgsrc": "http://x.com/picture_rendered_before_flash.jpg",
>
> "width": "80", 
> "height": "60",
> "expanded_width": "160", 
> "expanded_height": "120" }]}
> ```

Check out the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments) regarding attachments. There are examples for each of these categories.